# Optimize pagination query

Tags: mysql

I have 50K records in my table. This is my query.

```
SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE user_id > 10 AND status = 1 LIMIT 0,10
```

When I "EXPLAIN" this query it is still traversing 24959 rows. Can it be more optimizable so that it can traverse less rows?

[image]

Comment: you must show the create tables to see which indexes you have define for example one for user_id and status as combined index

Comment: [Use the Index, Luke !](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause)

Comment: please check I have uploaded table structure

Comment: If `password` is actually their password that is a big security problem; read [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 0):

You're filtering by both `user_id > 10` and `status = 1`.

There is no index on `status`.

`user_id > 10` will be nearly every row in the table. A full table scan will be faster than using the index.

So the optimizer has decided a full table scan will be fastest.

You can fix this by adding an index on `status`. A longer term solution might be to [partition the table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html) on `status`.

---

Side note: rather than relying on magic `user_id`s, consider adding [an explicit field](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) to `user` to indicate their role.